# Disconnect other IDE instances in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

I was wondering if there's a way to disconnect other IDE instances in Cloud9 IDE, because I left C9 IDE on at work and I have the code highlighted which makes it hard to work with when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to remotely disconnect other collaborators (which you became once you opened your workspace on multiple tabs), but you could disable collaboration altogether by adding `?collab=0` to the IDE URL, which should remove the code highlighting.